# Copy,Cut and Paste

Tags: wxpython

How to make copy,cut and paste in popup menu???

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Where are you with your research. (If this is the start of your research, please try to search first).  Do you have any code that isn't quite working? This question is too broad...

Comment: yes, i  have code, and this code showing all directory,and i  want to make copy,cut and paste in this code .......

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+C > Ctrl+x > Ctrl+v**

Basic window command.

Comment: thanx for answer, but i  don't meaning ctr+c,ctr+x and ctr+v,i  meaning how to make code in wxpython???